# Конфликт стилей в style.css

Tags: css

Итак. Есть 2 выпадающих меню.

Первый код css

```
* {
outline: 0;
font-family: sans-serif
}
body {
background-color: #fafafa
}
....
```

И второй код

```
body {
background: #2a2a2b;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
.....
```

Допустим это все пишется в файл style.css, применяется и получается конфликт c тегом body и применяется это ко всему сайту. Как сделать, чтобы стили применялись только к этим элементам и не конфликтовали между собой?

Comment: Я так и не понял, что конкретно вы хотите-то? Стили написаны для body — они и применяются для body и всех его наследников. Что ещё нужно-то?

Comment: Если вы хотите применить стили только к выпадающим меню — вот и пишите селекторы для выпадающих меню, а не для body

Comment: Создайте отдельный блок для меню приравняйте его к классу и делайте что угодно

Comment: Это понятно, я так и сделал  <div class ="menu-1" </div> , но тег body в css конфликтует и получется, что 2 разных по цвету меню становится одним цветом, так как из файла style.css берется последнее значение для тега body. Как правильно прописать стили для одного меню, второго?

Comment: Привидите конкретный пример и без "допустим", что и где у вас работает. Потому что ничего не понятно что и где у вас перекрывает, о каких меню и фонах идет речь.

Comment: @ДенисПулинец, нужно приводить весь код, чтобы видеть описанное вами явление. Но из того, что вы написали, достаточно реализовать селекторы для `body, #menu1, #menu2`, если идет переопределение свойств, надо удалять те каскады, которые переопределяют основные правила. Селекторы бывают разной вложенности, из-за этого и уровень привилегий у них повышается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас многостраничник с одним css файлом, но в конкретных страницах нужны иные стили, то задайте body класс и все стили применяйте этому классу.